# How to run PHP code in a JavaScript Function?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to make a function to open a webpage in the same tab as the one you are coming from, (think clicking on a bookmark in a tab). I have the page I want to go to and I know the PHP code to do what I want,

```
<?php
header("Location: example.php")
?>
```

I am wondering if there is a way for me to run PHP code in JavaScript so I can do what I want?

(Before anyone asks why I don't just run the code this way, it's because the situation I am in requires me to run the code through a JavaScript function)

Comment: why not just issue a `redirect` in plain `js` rather than using `php`?

Comment: @jpneey YOU ARE A GENIUS! Thank you soo much. I completely forgot this was a thing.

Comment: PHP executes on the Server before anything is sent to the Browser. In JavaScript, `location = 'yourURLHere'`  redirects. Yes, it's that easy.

Comment: Added an answer, incase you encounter another problem that requires you to call a `php` function on `js`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need PHP for page redirection. You can simply do this in pure javascript.

```js
function gotoExample() {
  window.location.href = './example.php';
}
```

Mixing PHP and javascript introduces complication to your code. Avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways on how you can run a `php` script inside a `js` function. One way is via ajax.

```
//some js logic here
if (foo) {
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
           console.log(this.responseText);
       }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://foo.bar/path/to/a/script.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

What happens on the above code is that when `foo` evaluates to `true`, than a `XMLHttpRequest` is called and a server side script written in `php` is executed.

However, in your case, it It is better to just handle a redirect on the client side rather than relying on PHP.

```
if (foo) {
   window.location.href = 'http://foo.bar/path/to/a/script.php';
}
```

There are various ways on how to issue a redirect via `js`. The interned is huge. You'll find it with just a couple of searches.

Comment: You could do `xhttp.onload = function(){`, instead of `xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {`. Also `location = 'http://foo.bar/path/to/a/script.php';` is fine. Just advice to make you type less.

Comment: Thanks @StackSlave that is a better approach